# Parsing XML with PHP?

Tags: php, xml

This has been driving me insane for about the last hour. I'm trying to parse a bit of XML out of Last.fm's API, I've used about 35 different permutations of the code below, all of which have failed. I'm really bad at XML parsing, lol. Can anyone help me parse the first toptags>tag>name 'name' from this XML API in PHP? :(

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=Owl+city&track=fireflies

Which in that case ^ would be 'electronic'

Right now, all I have is this

```
<?
$xmlstr = file_get_contents("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=Owl+city&track=fireflies");
$genre = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $genre->lfm->track->toptags->tag->name;
?>
```

Which returns with, blank. No errors either, which is what's incredibly annoying!

Thank You very Much :) :) :)

Any help greatly, and by greatly I mean really, really greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: $genre->track->toptags->tag[0]->name; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<tag>` tag is an array, so you should loop through them with a `foreach` or similar construct. In your case, just grabbing the first would look like this:

```
<?
$xmlstr = file_get_contents("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=Owl+city&track=fireflies");
$genre = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $genre->track->toptags->tag[0]->name;
```

Also note that the `<lfm>` tag is not needed.

**UPDATE**

I find it's much easier to grab exactly what I'm looking for in a SimpleXMLElement by using `print_r()`. It'll show you what's an array, what's a simple string, what's another SimpleXMLElement, etc.

Comment: I love you beyond comprehension. Thank you, very, very much. I tried the exact same thing, yet with the lfm directly before track, which didn't work. Thank you, very, very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=Owl+city&track=fireflies";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo $xml->track->toptags->tag[0]->name;
```

Comment: How would this help any? simplexml will just do a file_get_contents itself anyways (or use curl, whatever). In the end it'll still be loading the same xml and using the wrong tag path. `->tag-> is an array, not a single tag.

Comment: The code I pasted was the one without the array (I started trying loads of things, frustration :P file_get_contents and simplexml_load_file should pretty much do the same thing, except simpleXML's loader seems to run a bit slow on my server, which is why I stuck with file_get_contents -- Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: insert a statement to echo $xmlstr, and make sure you are getting *something* back from the API.

Comment: Ooh, thanks for the suggestion :) I do have to parse something else incase of failure though! :S Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reference `lfm`. Actually, `$genre` already is `lfm`. Try this:

```
echo $genre->track->toptags->tag->name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've got it working thanks to the first answer which was pretty much yours with an array value of 0 :) Thank you! :)

Comment: Yeah, it seems that if don't pass any index for `tag` array, it'll use the first. In this case, `eletronic`.

Answer (score 0):

if you wan't to read xml data please follow those steps,

$xmlURL = "your xml url / file name goes here";

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xmlURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: text/xml'
    ));
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $error   = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $obj = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($obj);
    echo "</pre>"; 
}
catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e);exit;
}
```

You will get array formate of whole xml file.

Thanks.